# is there is any easy way to detect attr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to detect if an element has any attribute its not specific . I just wanna know if there is any . And the if there is any attr i want to remove themm and add new attributes . And if there is not any new attributes will be added only.

### My codes are

```
if ($('.element').attr('style').length > 0) {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
}

$('.element').css({
    "top": (posY),
    "left":(posX)
});
```

but in console it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
Can any one help?

Comment: `attr('style')` returns a string (of the value) if it exists; undefined otherwise. The code is hitting the 'otherwise'.

Comment: You don't have to check at all, just call `removeAttr`

Comment: `$('.element').removeAttr('style').css({top:3});`, note that it only removes inline styles

Comment: I'm just curious.  Why are you even bothering to remove existing styles?  Why not just set the new styles you want?  They will replace whatever is currently there.

Comment: Is requirement to check for _any_ attribute set at any `.element`  , or only `style` attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if($('.element').attr('style') && $('.element').attr('style').length > 0){
     $('.element').removeAttr('style');
 }   

 $('.element').css({
    "top": (posY),
    "left": (posX)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly , try utilizing `.is()`

```
if ($(".element[style]").is("*")) {
  $(".element").attr("style", "top:" + (posY) + ";left:" + (posX))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.element').attr('style') === undefined){
```

Will test if the attribute is defined.